# How to access a radio button from a website in vba

Tags: vba, excel, date, calendar

Hello so I'm writing code in VBA excel that will access a database from a website. You have to input a date for the data you want on the website. They are radio buttons, so I was wondering how do you access them in vba code so that it always clicks that button. Also one of the options has a calendar view to input a start date and end date. How would you access this in vba. Thank you and all help is appreciated

This was a thought to access one button

```
IE.Document.getElementsById("(HTML Button Id)").Item.Click
```

Comment: IE.Document.getElementsById("(HTML Button Id)").Checked = True/False depending if you want it checked or not. Important Edit: Just in case a JavaScript is fired up whenever it is checked or not, you do this right after: IE.Document.getElementsById("(HTML Button Id)").FireEvent ("onclick")

Comment: Is there a URL to share please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Radio:

```
IE.Document.getElementsById("(HTML Button Id)").Checked = True
```

Uncheck Radio:

```
IE.Document.getElementsById("(HTML Button Id)").Checked = False
```

Recommended/Required you do the following if you are Checking the radio/checkbox (True)

Fire Up any JavaScript attached to the Radio Button:

```
IE.Document.getElementsById("(HTML Button Id)").FireEvent ("onclick")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello thanks for the responses but after some trial and error I found that this code is what worked for me!

Set radio = IE.Document.all
    radio.Item("Radio Button Name")(0).Checked = True

The (O) represents which radio button to use because in my case the website I was using had multiple radio button options and the one I wanted clicked was the first one.